# yet another weird SciPy/Gfortran snag

Tags: macos, scipy, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to install `gfortran` on my computer via terminal (Mac OS Yosemite 10.10), and I come across this message:

```
running build_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
customize NAGFCompiler
Could not locate executable f95
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
customize IBMFCompiler
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize PGroupFCompiler
Could not locate executable pgfortran
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
building 'dfftpack' library
error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
comp:scipy me$ gfortran --version gfortran: 
warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
```

It looks like a bunch of executables are missing, but I don't think that is what is going on. I am quite a neophyte when it comes to this stuff, so ask me if there is missing information that might help.

Comment: Though I'm not familiar with OSX, I suspect that those "Could not locate executable" messages are just warnings telling you that the only fortran compiler it found was `gfortran`. Then it says "don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'", which might be the reason why it can't compile the library for you. Wait: are you trying to install gfortran or scipy...?

Comment: The message printed when you run `gfortran --version` is strange.  Are you sure your installation of `gfortran` is correct?  Can you compile a simple "Hello world"-type Fortran program?

Comment: so what i was doing was installing SciPy, but it failed.  was prompted to install gfortran when i read about why it wouldn't work in a forum post by someone with a similar issue.

Comment: i do not think that the gfortran installed properly, because even a simple "hello world" won't go.  though, i have resolved the issue with scipy, as Homebrew actually went through with it.  i have no idea why, and i am wondering if i am tying my computer into knots. :S